# Unable to perform like query with parameter using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I'm trying to pass a variable as a parameter in an access query so I can generate a list of similar names on my website. I'm using pyodbc to access a .mdb database for my flask app. I tried passing a variable in many ways like...

```
xyz = "SomeName"
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeName LIKE %?%', xyz)
```

it didn't work so I tried...

```
xyz = "SomeName"
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeName LIKE ?', "%xyz%")
```

this one is a no-brainer. The variable is no longer a variable in double quotes so it runs 'xyz' as a string. But the query works when I pass it as just a string...

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeName LIKE ?', "%SomeName%")
```

How do I pass a user input variable to make this query work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `&` to concatenate the strings in ms-access:

```
xyz = "SomeName"
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeName LIKE "%" & ? & "%"', xyz)
```

Alternatively, you can concatenate the string variable in Python:

```
xyz = "SomeName"
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeName LIKE ?', '%' + xyz + '%')
```

Comment: Access driver doesn't seem to recognise 'concat()'. I got the error... 'pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Undefined function 'CONCAT' in expression. (-3102) (SQLExecDirectW)") '

Comment: @AshwinKrishnaraj: yes I noticed the `ms-access` tag afterwards; you can use the `&` operator instead of `concat()`.

Comment: I tried 'EmployeeName LIKE %&?&%' and got "Syntax error in query expression 'EmployeeName LIKE %&Pa_RaM000&%". I also tried 'EmployeeName LIKE "%"&?&"%"' and got 'Too few parameters. Expected 2'.